# How to get html page with frames in python

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to get contents of an html page using following code:

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request(req_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response.read()
```

It returns following response instead of the original page:

```
<html xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:stringutils="xalan://org.apache.tools.ant.util.StringUtils">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Test Results</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="20%,80%">
<frameset rows="30%,70%">
<frame src="overview-frame.html" name="packageListFrame">
<frame src="allclasses-frame.html" name="classListFrame">
</frameset>
<frame src="overview-summary.html" name="classFrame">
<noframes>
<h2>Frame Alert</h2>
<p>
                This document is designed to be viewed using the frames feature. If you see this message, you are using a non-frame-capab
le web client.
            </p>
</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

How can I get contents of the original html page?

Comment: page is divided in a frameset... so the original html page is so to be recovered in each of the frame pages

Comment: Or, in other words, that is the original page it just references other components that comprise what you see. Just as an `<img>` tag has a `src=` component which needs to be retrieved separately, so does a `<frame>` tag. The proper way to get at the subordinate URLs is a HTML parser like lxml or BeautifulSoup. Do **not** use regular expressions as they cannot parse HTML.